# Why does the if and else both get executed on scroll?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll, angular-directive

I got this really strange behaviour for my scroll event, I just can't seem to figure it why this happens or how to fix it. Basically what I have is an event listener that listens to scrolling, but both the if and else is getting executed on scroll..

I got this directive:

```
core.directive('offsetColor', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var windowY = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elementY = element.offset().top - 60; // -60 to add site header height

        if (elementY <= windowY) {
          console.log('element is at top');
        }
        else {
          console.log('no element is at top');
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Whos task is to change the site header's color based on the y position of certain elements.

Currently I have set this directive on two elements.

Now my simple guess to why this is happening is because I've set the directive on **two** elements and not **one**, therefore the scroll event "loops" through both of the elements and checking their y position. So one of the elements is at the top but the other one is not, causing both the `if` and `else` to be executed.

I feel like I've tried everything to stop it from executing both but I come up with no solution.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might need an external scope variable to sync both objects, so if one goes to the if the other don't go

Comment: Your simple guess looks to be spot on. The two window.onscroll handlers will compete and one (the last one to be attached) will determine the  header's color. What you need is **one** window.onscroll handler that reads the position of all relevant elements and determines the header's color in accordance with whatever rule you want.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: Not really because I don't understand the `core.directive()` wrapper or the meaning of `restrict`. In raw jQuery, you would simply wrap `$window.on('scroll', ...)` in `$.(function() {...})`.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You can just put the logic in one parent directive instead of several directives on the elements themselves. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0):

As Roamer-1888 mentioned in the comments, in order to resolve a problem like this, you need to consolidate your event handlers (the scroll listeners, in this case).

Here's one idea: create a directive and apply it to a *common ancestor* of all of the elements that change the header's color. Add the scroll listener on the window inside of this directive.

Now, either by using jQuery, or by using child directives that talk to the parent directive ([like the AngularJS tabs example](https://angularjs.org/#create-components)), loop through all of the elements that could change the header's color. Grab their offsets from the window position, and then find the one with the smallest offset.

The element with the smallest offset is the one that should affect the header color.

All in all, your directive would look something like this (going the jQuery route; the nested directive route is left as an exercise to the read) (untested):

```
core.directive('offsetColorContainer', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var colorElems = $('.some-selector-that-identifies-your-color-elems', element);

      $window.on('scroll', function() {
        var windowY = $(window).scrollTop(),
            closestElem = null,
            closestDist = null;

        colorElems.each(function() {
          var elem = $(this),
              elemDist = Math.abs(elem.offset().top - windowY);

          if (closestElem === null || elemDist < closestDist)
          {
            closestElem = elem;
            closestDist = elemDist;
          }
        });

        if (closestElem !== null)
        {
          // change the header color based on closestElem
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Note that you may need to tweak the element distance logic depending on what your elements actually represent, but that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Can't make the each loop work for some reason, it doesn't go through the elements in colorElems even though I have items in it.

Comment: Check your console and make sure there aren't any problems. Put some `console.log` statements, or, better yet, use the JS debugger. `.each()` should work fine.

Comment: I have, everything runs except for the each.

Comment: Well, the `.each()` call must be running, but it must be running on an empty set of elements. Do a `console.log(colorElems)` and see what it outputs. Make sure that the list of elements is not empty. If the list of elements is not empty, then the `.each()` call is definitely running, but something inside of it must be wrong. Add `console.log()` calls inside the `.each()` call to figure it out.